# What factors affect the amount of microwave absorption?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, microwaves

I am planning to do an investigation on factors affecting the amount of microwave absorption. I understand how microwave radiation heats objects, but do factors such as color affect the amount of microwave absorption?

Moreover, if I were to use the same substance (ex.water), what factors would affect how fast the substance heats up?

Comment: How is the microwave radiation being emitted? Are you using a direct microwave beam or are you using a microwave cavity?

Comment: What's the purpose of your "investigation"?

Comment: Due to high complexity this matter is mostly experimental. The best absorbers seem to be graphite, iron oxide ($Fe_2O_3$ if I recall) and their equal mix.